# Как влияет CMS на продвижение сайта?

Tags: cms, seo, движок

Привет всем! Вопрос такой: в моем распоряжении есть несколько сайтов, все коммерческой тематики, соответственно, вопрос ранжирования крайне важен, но заметил такую вещь, что сайты с разных движков и даже с версий выводятся в ТОП по-разному. И даже молодой сайт занимает позиции выше, чем старый, если версия движка новее. Поэтому у меня назрел вопрос: действительно CMS настолько серьезно влияем на продвижение? И тогда каким движкам лучше отдавать предпочтение?

Comment: Вы уверены что дело в движке, а не, например, в скорости отдачи контента?

Answer (score 2):

На каких движках у вас сайты? Если говорить о Joomla, то я читал, что в версии 3.0 был основательно почищен код, по сравнению, например, с той же Joomla 2.5. На практике это не проверял, но вроде как действительно так. А вообще, для таких целей старайтесь использовать движки, в которых изначально учитывается вопрос продвижения. Даже сайты на битриксе ранжируются гораздо лучше, но там стоимость нехилая за пользование и часто она себя не окупает. Я в последнее время подсел на  dotplant2, всякого мусора лишнего в коде по-минимому, функционал уже для сео-продвижения, сео-правки без проблем вносятся, плюс вообще система легко костюмируется под различные шаблоны и функционал, сможете реализовать все, что угодно на ней. И сайт на нем неплохо кстати лезет в выдаче, хотя молодой и тематика очень конкурентная.

Answer (score 0):

Сама CMS никак не влияет. Может влиять конкретный templaate-шаблон (тема) в cms и как в нем что организовано, какие-то плагины, влияющие на тот или иной уважаемый поисковиками фактор, и т.п. (Версию CMS, при желании, как правило, вообще можно от поисковика спрятать.) Наблюдаемая же тобой разница, считаю, зачастую связана с тем, что "старики", окопавшись в какой-то устраивающей их нише, уже не уделяют столько внимания поисковым раскруткам (а, порой, и вовсе на них забивают). По крайней мере, если человек не находит времени/желания обновлять до актуальной версии CMS своего сайта (хотя с этим, например, связана такая не мало важная вещь, как безопасность сайта), то, зачастую, и заморачиваться в серьез с мероприятиями по его продвижению, в т.ч., при необходимости, как-то его под это дело улучшать, перестраивать, что-то где-то добавлять и прописывать и т.д., он тоже не будет - отсюда и наблюдаемый тобой рсклад.

Answer (score 0):

Не только сами CMS влияют на продвигаемость сайта, если смотреть со стороны тех. оптимизации. Модули, которые установлены могут крайне негативно влиять на сайт. К этому можно отнести появление дублей станиц (привет, Joomla), добавление в шаблон лишней ненужной информации. Если брать в расчет само построение модуля, то могут применяться не совсем логичные теги, такие как `<h2-h6>`, `<b>` или `<i>`. Что тоже негативно влияет на сайт. Тут уже не так важно, какая CMS используется. Интересно было бы узнать, если у ТС сайты html, и если да, то как они себя ведут в топе?

Answer (score 0):

Чем уникальнее содержимое сайта, тем он лучше продвигается. то есть если вы берете шаблон и дополняете его, то это еже не достаточно уникально. советую всем владельцам делать свои шаблоны для каждого сайта

Comment: Вы противоречите сами себе. Влияет СОДЕРЖИМОЕ сайта. Шаблон, разметка, верстка - это НЕ СОДЕРЖИМОЕ сайта.

Comment: Я к тому, что и сам сайт должен быть уникальным, а не только его контент. так как поисковики обращают внимание и на это тоже

Comment: Приведите, если не затруднит, источник такой удивительной информации.